# ionic Gulpfile (or dependent module) not found

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, gulp, ionic3

I'm trying to open a project that i downloaded from github.the project uses ionic 2 but it returns this error :

```
[ERROR] Gulpfile (or dependent module) not found: .\gulpfile.js

        For custom Gulpfile locations, you can run ionic config set gulp.file
        <path>. Otherwise, the default Ionic Gulpfile can be downloaded from
        https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-base/blob/master/gulpfile.js

        Or, if you don't use gulp, you can disable it by running ionic config
        set gulp.enabled false.
        Full error:

        Error: Cannot find module 'ionic-gulp-sass-build'
            at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:538:15)
            at Function.Module._load (module.js:468:25)
            at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
            at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
            at Object.<anonymous> (F:\ionic3\exemple
        taxi\Ionic-2-Uber-master\gulpfile.js:31:17)
            at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
            at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
            at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
            at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
            at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
```

i tried some solutions like :

> 1-Delete your node_modules folder
>
> 2-Remove gulp-sass from your package.json file
>
> 3-Remove node-sass from your package.json file (if you have it in there)
>
> 4-Run npm install gulp-sass --save-dev

Also this one :

> 1-update version-clean
>
> 2-the node_module and executenpm install
>
> 3-may be npm cache

But i still have the same error .Is it that i installed ionic3 and the project runs in ionic 2 the cause of the problem ?